# Share code between projects with webpack and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, dllplugin

I've the following structure:

- Project1

  - app.ts
  - tsconfig.json
  - webpack.config.js
- ProjectShared

  - shared.ts
  - tsconfig.json
  - webpack.config.js

ProjectShared generates a DllPlugin with "./shared.ts" and for example "jquery" and Project1 references it. In my HTML of Project1 I want to include that referenced vendor.js and the bundle.js.

Now when I import for example `jquery` from Project1 it's using the code from the DLL so that part works as expected. (./node_modules/jquery is the same in both contexts)

However if I import "../ProjectShared/shared" it compiles but this code is not included from the DLL but in the bundle again. (../ProjectShared/shared.ts is not the same as ./shared.ts)

If I then switch the context of the ReferencePlugin to ../ProjectShared/ it works but jquery won't be used from DLL then. (./node_modules/jquery != ../ProjectShared/node_modules/jquery)

I can see why that happens (different contexts) but what if I want to share code between that two projects without having to move them to modules but also want modules to be shared aswell?

I can see that it might work if instead of "jquery" I use "../ProjectShared/node_modules/jquery" cause then the context is the same again. But that looks ugly even if I use paths in tsconfig or resolve.alias in webpack.

What is the recommended way to do something like that?